# Generating all the combinations, even missing ones, when aggregating data

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to do aggregate using `by` in `data.table` so that all the unique values of fields mentioned in the `by` clause are returned? Consider the below example:

```r
> m <- as.data.table(mtcars)
> m[, .N, by=.(cyl, gear)]
   cyl gear  N
1:   6    4  4
2:   4    4  8
3:   6    3  2
4:   8    3 12
5:   4    3  1
6:   4    5  2
7:   8    5  2
8:   6    5  1
>
```

Notice that the row for `cyl=8` and `gear=4` is missing? I can generate this using the following:

```r
merge(m[,.(expand.grid(cyl=unique(cyl),gear=unique(gear)))],
+     m[,.N,by=.(cyl,gear)], 
+     all.x=TRUE)
Key: <cyl, gear>
   cyl gear  N
1:   4    3  1
2:   4    4  8
3:   4    5  2
4:   6    3  2
5:   6    4  4
6:   6    5  1
7:   8    3 12
8:   8    4 NA
9:   8    5  2
>
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to generate the above using `data.table` syntax?  For e.g., something like `tidyr::complete` which I learned from https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2020/07/23/tidyrcomplete-to-show-all-possible-combinations-of-variables/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'casting' to wide will also yield desired output.

```
dcast(m, cyl + gear ~ ., value.var = "mpg", fun.aggregate = length, drop = FALSE )

#    cyl gear  .
# 1:   4    3  1
# 2:   4    4  8
# 3:   4    5  2
# 4:   6    3  2
# 5:   6    4  4
# 6:   6    5  1
# 7:   8    3 12
# 8:   8    4  0
# 9:   8    5  2
```

`drop = FALSE` is key here, since it keeps 'empty' groups.
from the comment by@Markus: `fill = NA` will fill empty groups with `NA`-value

Comment: Good answer! One tiny remark: maybe use `fill = NA`?! That is, `dcast(m, cyl + gear ~ ., value.var = "mpg", drop = FALSE, fill = NA)`

Comment: Good answer, @Wimpel! And, good point @markus. I had not thought of casting. Very nice! Thanks for your ideas!